Solving non-homogeneous second order linear differential equations with variable coefficients
This question appeared in the final question paper of our mathematics module.

Question
Let $y = f_1(x)$ and $y = f_2(x)$ be solutions of
$$y'' + 2x^2 y' - 4xy = 2e^{x^2} \sin(x),$$
such that $f_1(1) = 1,$ $f_2(1) = -1,$ $f_1'(0) = 1$ and $f_2'(0) = 2$. The value of the Wronskian $W(f_1, f_2)$ at $x = 0$ is

(A) $3$
(B) $0$
(C) $e$
(D) $e^2$
(E) $-1$
(F) None of the above


My attempt
Since $W(f_1,f_2) = \begin{vmatrix} f_1 & f_2 \\ f_1' & f_2' \end{vmatrix},$ To find $W(f_1,f_2)(0)$ which is $f_1(0)f_2'(0) - f_2(0)f_1'(0),$ We need to evaluate $f_1(0)$ and $f_2(0)$. Is there any trick to get these 2 values, which I don't see?
I believe it is not possible to solve this problem without at least knowing the form of the solutions. If I can solve the homogeneous form of the equation:
$$y'' + 2x^2 y' - 4xy = 0$$
I would be able to determine the exact solutions. I have tried assuming several forms of solutions and I'm pretty sure the solutions to the homogeneous equation are not in the form of $y=e^{ax^b}$ (where $a$, $b$ are constants) because applying this form to the equation gives contradictive values for $a$ and $b$. I am unsure how to approach solving this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

What is the formula for the Wronskian at a point $x$? In particular it's enough to know the initial conditions, and you needn't find the solutions

@TravisWillse Yeah it's enough if I can find $f_1(0)$ and  $f_2(0)$, but I have no idea how to do it. It would be helpful you can elaborate more.

Ah, I didn't see that the initial conditions were at different points!

The homogeneous form of the equation does not appear to have a solution in elementary functions. Mathematica finds a general solution in terms of parabolic cylinder functions.

I don't see how this problem can be solved analytically with the information provided. I've solved the ODE numerically in Mathematica for each given set of boundary conditions, and I find that $f_1(0) = -0.343201$ and $f_2(0) = -2.28113$, which yields $W(f_1, f_2)(0) = 1.59473$. This implies that the correct answer is (F) None of the above.
